# Create new file with Values only from one tab in an Excel workbook

Tags: vba

I'm trying to use VBA to copy values only from a single tab in an excel workbook (workbook title "workbook1" for simplicity) into a new workbook that will then prompt the user to save the new file. The tab within "workbook1" is called "OUTPUT" and new file should maintain formating. How do I do this?

```
Sub nowe()
    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Set Output = Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTPUT").Cells.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                           SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

This worked, but didn't paste values:

```
Sub GetQuote()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT").Copy
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

Comment: you start by giving us something to work with, your code attmepts. share screen-shots of your data, and desired result.

Comment: I tried this....

Sub nowe()

Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTPUT").Cells.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


End Sub

Comment: It just needs to be the entirety of the tab, so the data within that tab shouldn't matter. I don't want to limit it to a range.

Comment: This worked, but didn't paste values

Sub GetQuote()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT").Copy
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub

Comment: It's because you're saying paste to selection, but you haven't selected anything.

Comment: So how do i tweak the code to fix the selection piece and still paste special values?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (I commented the code, for better explanation)

```
Sub CopyOutput()

    'Define Variable
    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    'Create New Workbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    'Copy Worksheet "OUTPUT" into new Workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT").Copy After:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

    'Disable Screen updates, delete the first (empty) tab, the new worbook was created with, then reactivate screen updates
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    NewBook.Sheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Open Save as dialog
    Application.GetSaveAsFilename

End Sub
```

Let me know if that works

Best
seulberg1